# Get Build date in unity standalone build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking for a way to get build `DateTime` so that a user/QA can get the executable release date. For this reason, I can make a variable or a textfile where I update the `DateTime` when building the executable. Then later I retrieve the date from the file or variable. The problem is, with each build I have to update the `DateTime` in a file or in a variable. Is there any Built-in way available in Unity or [Application class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.html) to do this? I found nothing related to this.

I found this code snippet on Stack form but is returning nothing:

```
string GetPlayerBuildDate()
{
    var version = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version;
    DateTime buildDateTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).Add(new TimeSpan(
    TimeSpan.TicksPerDay * version.Build + // days since 1 January 2000
    TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * 2 * version.Revision));
    Debug.Log("GetPlayerDate Assembly" + buildDateTime);
    return buildDateTime.Year.ToString();
}
```

Comment: you could look into creating a script that automatically adds a file containing the build time alongside the build project using the [Build Player PipeLine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html), From the docs (emphasis mine): "*For example you might want to add a custom icon, **copy some documentation** next to the player or build an Installer.*". This way it will update the build time automatically. I don't think there is a build-in method for it.

Comment: this is the kind of job that are usually handles by continuous integration or deployment pipelines. as the answer from Remy says you have tools that are made for that. If your project is on a git plateform like github there is usually tools for that too like github actions.

Comment: @Remy Yes you are right but i have to write my own build system with UI for this.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my earlier comment earlier you can completely automate including a `.txt` file with your build containing the date/time of the build by using the [Build Player PipeLine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html). Without the need to create your own build system with UI (unless I misunderstood, and you have your own build system. But even then it can be incorporated into that as well).

Important: The post processor script needs to be in a folder called `Editor`, if it is not it *will* throw errors when building. In my example the script is in /Assets/Scripts/Editor/PostBuildScript.cs

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class BuildScript
{
    //Script is called after the building process, BuildTarget and string pathToBuiltProject are mandatory arguments
    [PostProcessBuildAttribute(1)]
    public static void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget target, string pathToBuiltProject)
    {
        //Give the user a file folder pop-up asking for the location you wish to save the file to
        string path = EditorUtility.SaveFolderPanel("Save location", "", "");
        //Alternative you can also just hardcode the path..
        //string path = "C:/Dev/Unity/MyProject/MyBuilds/

        //Get the current datetime and convert it to a string with some explanatory text
        string date = string.Format("Build date: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());

        //Write the date to a text file called "BuildDate.txt" at the selected location
        File.WriteAllText(path + "BuildDate.txt", date);
    }
}
```

Now after building the "BuildDate.txt" file will be included in the selected location, containing the DateTime of the build (e.g `Build date: 19/02/2020 20:29:30`)